# Algorithm to sort a list in Θ(n) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time, analysis

The problem is to sort a list containing n distinct integers that range in value from 1 to kn inclusive where k is a fixed positive integer.  Design an algorithm to solve the problem in Θ(n) time.

I don't just want an answer. An explanation would help, or if someone could get me pointed in the right direction.

I know that Θ(n) time means the algorithm time is directly proportional to the number of elements. Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: The best algorithm that I know is the [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: If k=9 and n=7, how would the list look?

Comment: @Maertin well, we would see that the list contains 7 values ranging from 1 to 63. We could say [10,55,1,23,43,5,20] is the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy for fixed k: Create an array of kn counters. Set them all to zero. Iterate through the array, increasing the counter i by one if an array element equals i. Use the array of counters to re-create the sorted array.

Obviously this is inefficient if k > log n.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why I need to iterate from 1 to kn, and not 1 to n. There is only n numbers, so why do i need to make kn sized array?

Comment: You're saying, I should write "for i=1 to kn do: counter[i]=0"?

Comment: As mentioned this depends on the value of k, and if kn counters will fit in memory. If k is too large, then the array of counters will be mostly zero, but even if slower, it's still O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the integers only range from 1 to kn, so their length is limited.  This is a little tricky:

The common assumption when we say that a sorting algorithm is O(N) is that the number N fits into a constant number of machine words so that we can do math on numbers of that size in constant time.  *Following this assumption*, kN *also* fits into a constant number of machine words, since k is a *fixed* positive integer.  Your input is therefore O(N) words long, and each word is fixed number of bits, so your input is O(N) bits long.

Therefore, any algorithm that takes time proportional to the number of bits in the input is considered O(N).

There are actually lots of choices, but when this particular question is asked in this particular way, the person asking usually wants you to come up with a radix sort:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

The MSB-first radix sort just partitions the integers into 2^W buckets according to the values of their top W bits, and then partitions each bucket according to the next W bits, etc., until all the bits are processed.

The time taken for this is O(N*(word_size/W)), but as we said the word size is constant, and W is constant, so this is O(N).